# Question with multiple downvotes, having more than five answers

Tags: discussion, voting

I mostly observed this, and I am sure most of you, too.

I have seen many questions that have 20+ downvotes. The same questions have been answered by more than five people. One of the answers is accepted, too. And the answers have many upvotes.

I am not clear about following points:

- If a question is downvoted by multiple users, it means that the question is not useful or unclear.
- Why do people keep answering such unclear questions?
- Why do many users upvote answers on unclear and not useful questions?

Is there a need for a policy from Stack Overflow regarding this or should users need to rethink before answering or downvoting?

Comment: Just because a question lacks research doesn't mean it is unanswerable. Just because a question is downvoted doesn't mean that the answers don't have value.

Comment: *"Why people keep answering that unclear question?"* Mainly to earn cheap reputation points. The actual quality and usefulness for this site doesn't matter much for them. *"Why many user's up voted that answer"* I wouldn't be surprised when these answerers upvote each others answers.

Comment: *"Why many users up vote answers on unclear and not useful questions?"* If the answer was helpful for me I upvote it (regardless how bad the question is).

Comment: @testing: how can a answer to a unclear question be helpful? If it's not clear what the question is, how can it possibly be answered?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Take for example an error message. You search for that in Google and find a SO post, where the error message is quoted. The question can be bad and even unclear, but if an answer had a tip, which solved my problem, it is helpful. As Martijn said, the question can still have a value. And if such a highly down voted question, has many upvoted answers, this is one of this special edge cases.

Comment: Yes anyone will upvote if it is useful. But this can lead to multiple answers for same question and isn't is sounds messy ?

Comment: Most of these questions are just ground bait.  The rest of the voting ring and/or rep-personalSevicesWorkers circle in a feeding frenzy and they all get an uvote or two:(   At the end, all you get is muddy water.

Comment: In first go, user never know what things are needed to give answer to this question, so he provide very less details. Later on, according to the demands of answer-er he will update his question but till then the question got enough downvotes -> I think.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with multiple answers to a single question, why do you think that would be bad?

Comment: Thats because there is one group of people who are interested in downvoting all the rubbish and duplicate questions they see, and there is also another group of people who are interested in answering every question they possibly can in the desperate hope for reputation, no matter how badly asked or duplicated the question might be.  Its just two different interest groups doing two different things.  Your questions are not very good either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688297/non-consumable-in-app-purchases-for-30k-items

Comment: One thing to also consider is how many of those questions got hit by the meta effect (or something similar) to get those downvotes.

Comment: @Cerbrus I ran into [a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/96478/75627) the other day that had a comment that said that the question was unclear. Yet I was able to answer the question. Why? Because despite the apparently vague wording, I knew what the Asker was going on about (with about 80% certainty: enough to propose a well constructed answer).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When I see voting like you described, more often than not, the question isn't unclear, it's just a basic dupe:

- The question is extremely basic, lacking research, and often a duplicate.
- The answers are (more or less) *correct*.
- The question gets downvoted because of its lack of research / it's a dupe / it's just programming 101.
- The answers get upvoted because people recognize them as correct.

People answer questions like that because it's easy rep.

Preferably, the question would be closed as duplicate, instead.

---

That said, I think people are way too **reluctant to downvote** low quality Q/A.

Similarly, the rep reward is often more appealing than close-voting a question as a duplicate, even to users that can single-handedly close a question as duplicate, with a gold badge in one of the question's tags.

Personally, I downvote answers on extremely obvious duplicates.
For example:

[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) *"How do I round off this number to the nearest `0.5`?"*

Asked on a daily basis, easy to answer, easy rep.
Answering that correctly will guarantee you a couple of upvotes for a minute of writing.
Closing that as duplicate (assuming a gold badge in JavaScript) doesn't give you any rewards... Other than improving the overall quality of SO's Q/A.

Comment: That means user need to re think about down voting a question at first place ? and for "single-handedly close a question as duplicate", Stack Overflow need to update/Recheck their policy

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ: Basically: Downvote more. It's easy to compensate the lost rep with a answer elsewhere. Why do you think SO needs to recheck the close-as-duplicate policy?

Comment: Because if a question is getting answer from many user's as a valid question , but one user with gold badge come and mark it as duplicate even if it isn't ?

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ: The fact that a question is getting answered doesn't mean it's a good question. The point is that people shouldn't answer duplicates. They should close-vote instead. The problem isn't that an answered question is getting closed. The problem is that it was answered in the first place.

Comment: I am agree with your this point "Basically: Downvote more", But if one is going to answer it , he should check if it is already answered or not.

Comment: It comes down to this: A lot of users are _greedy for rep._ They don't care it's a duplicate. They don't care it's been answered before.

Comment: Yes @Cerbrus this can be the issue. So one must show responsibility as a professional  to check before answering just for repo.

Comment: Ideally, yes. Users _should_ check for dupes before answering. But sadly, a lot of users just don 't care.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is no, but shouldn't we downvote answers to obvious duplicates? Alternatively the rep gained from answers to questions closed as duplicates should be removed.

Comment: @IanS: _I_ downvote such answers. And I'd love for rep gained from answers on dupes to be removed.

Comment: @Nathan: Closed questions can still receive upvotes. You just rewarded the OP that didn't do their research by answering the question. This encourages them to just ask again without research. Also, people ___can vote however they want___. I don't think answers to obvious duplicates are useful ___at all___, even if they're correct. That's why I downvote them.

Comment: (This is exactly what I mean with users being too reluctant to downvote.)

Comment: _"Ideally, the accepted answer in theses cases should be "[duplicate of this](127.0.0.1)"_ Nope, that doesn't answer the question at all. That's the whole point of closing the question as a duplicate: A ___big___ banner appears at the top linking to a proper answer. Answering the question just spreads out the information all over the place. Besides, dupe targets automatically get more search engine score.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144321/discussion-between-nathan-and-cerbrus).

Comment: I wonder if what's missing is a rep bonus for (only low-rep users?) correctly flagging (and vote-closing?) questions as duplicates rather than answering the question. My "fastest gun in the west" times are only a year behind me, so I remember times where I'd find a question and in the process of doing the research to answer it, find that it was a dupe (or just knowing) and feeling a little bummed that I got no reward for doing the right thing. Even just 5 rep for flagging/voting instead of answering might be enough. It's less rep than an up-vote, but encourages proper behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you shouldn't downvote **correct, researched answers**. This is a personal opinion, but for me it is like feeding a criminal: Even though this criminal (the duplicate poster) will get arrested and punished (question closed/downvoted/flagged), I believe you shouldn't punish (downvote) the one who fed him (the answerer).

> Why many users up vote answers on unclear and not useful questions?

Sometimes, the answer is better than the original one, or the question is better asked / formulated. If I type a question and end up on a question marked as a duplicate, but the answer is useful to me, I **will** mark it as useful and upvote it. If I ended up on this question/answer, it means that the question was closer to my needs.

[This SO blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) has a good point by saying:

> ... it’s OK for duplicate questions to have duplicate answers. While you could argue that the duplicate questions could all be merged into one question with a “master” set of answers, this is kind of irritating from the perspective of the user looking for an answer. Put yourself in their shoes. Instead of finding …
>
> ```
> Duplicate Question
> Duplicate Answer
> ```
>
> They have to deal with finding:
>
> ```
> Duplicate Question
> [closed as duplicate of Question] click here to see answers
> ```

So to help future users that may end up on the same question, I feel it is better to duplicate the answers for the specific problem (even if the questions have the same cause).

Comment: If the answer is better than the original one, you can mention the better part with reference to old answer. Yes anyone will upvote if it is useful. But  this can lead to multiple answers for same question and isn't is sounds messy ?

Comment: If the new Q/A is better than the old one, the old one should be closed as duplicate of the new one.

Comment: ^^^ then they both get closed as opinions.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes it can be , New one can also edit the old to make it best , Instead starting a new one.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can't close a question as duplicate of a new one '-' What you can do is suggest to the author of the previous question to update his/her/its question, or ask a moderator to do it.

Comment: @Nathan: Why not? If the new one is significantly better, there's no rule against it. Older questions rarely get updated.

Comment: @Cerbrus If a question from 2 years ago cannot be reproduced anymore - it was a bug on an old software version for example - you won't flag the question as "Not reproductible bug, ...", because it wasn't the case at this time, you'll edit the question to specify that the bug doesn't apply anymore. Retroactiveness is almost **never** a good decision. Marking a good question as duplicate because of a **future** question is plainly wrong.

Comment: Marking older questions as duplicates of newer ones happens on a daily basis, @Nathan. And for good reason. Older questions don't always get updated, even if you leave a comment. Your example is irrelevant. A 2 year old question that can't be reproduced any more won't get a new duplicate. You also don't edit a 2-year-old question if the bug it was about was fixed later. But if a newer question explains the same subject better than a old question did, that old question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Bad metaphor, [aiding and abetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiding_and_abetting) a criminal is itself a crime.

Comment: As usual, the problem with this logic is that it assumes downvotes are punishments. They aren't. Votes are a ranking system. If an answer is correct, but is *less useful* or *less complete* than another, competing answer, it might make perfect sense to downvote the sub-par answer while upvoting the better answer.

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps I hold this view because I myself is quite new to programming and its community, but is it really such a heinous crime to ask a "basic" or duplicate question if you're a complete beginner? If you're new and learning, the process of *researching, reading other people's examples and realising they're about the same problem you have*, is not that easy. Usually those questions are really easy to answer too, so no harm done by helping them out.

My opinion is that you shouldn't be too hard on people just getting started with programming if they get stuck with really basic stuff and need a hand. I'd hold back on downvoting them, and encourage anyone helping them out.

Comment: * throws manual * RTFM. Read before posting. Most basic questions are just homework assignments. If they had bothered to put their question title into google they would have gotten the answer. Or had bothered to click on the suggested list.

Comment: There's no reason to be so hostile. Yeah sure, some questions are just basic homework. But sometimes the asker is someone learning programming on their own (no teachers or classmates to help). Being helpful and encouraging isn't a bad thing.

Comment: This isn't about being hard , It is about searching. If you are new , You should search more and than come to ask question. StacK Overflow is to help when you stuck at some point. Stuck means you tries every thing you can do including search, solutions , effort etc. What if you tried once ? searched for 5 minute or less and go for posting a question ?

Comment: `Being helpful and encouraging isn't a bad thing.`  Sure, but doing other people's google searches for them because they can't be bothered isn't being helpful and encouraging.  It's being actively harmful, taking away learning opportunities for them, creating low quality content throughout the site, and wasting lots of people's time.  Everyone involved is worse off as a result.